# How to import javascript function, stored in db.system.js, in query

Tags: mongodb

I created this javascrip function  for base64 decoding.

```
db.system.js.insertOne({_id: "decode64", value: function(doc) { // do the decode } })
```

but when I tried to use with query like this

```
db.getCollection("attendance").find({status: "late"}).map(function(doc) { return decode64(doc.serealizedData) })
```

it throws an error `decode64 is not defined` eventhough I already added it to system.js Is there a way to import it?